# Unable to get comment list in post using gremlin query

Tags: graph, gremlin, rexster

I'm having following vertex and edges.

```
User1 -> create ->Post1
Post1 -> postedOnWall -> User2
User2 -> create ->Comment1
Comment1 -> PostedOnComment -> Post1
User3 -> create -> Comment2
Comment2 -> PostedOnComment -> Post1
```

User1 created Post1 and Posted it on User2's Wall. Now User2 Created a Comment and posted it on Post1. and User3 also posted comment on same post.

How can I get the list of all post on user's wall along with all comments in each posts.

I'm getting list of post by following query :

> g.v(512).in('*label','WallPost').sort{it.PostedTime}.reverse().*().as('postInfo')[0..10].in('*label','Comment').*().as('comment').select{it}{it}

Am not able to find any way to get list of comments on each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `select()` step gets you pretty close, but I think a `transform()` might be what you're looking for. I've posted a full Gremlin Console session result in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/pluradj/f33b73489aab19082571), but the key part is this:

```
gremlin> g.V('name','user2').in('PostedOnWall').sort{ a, b -> b.PostedTime <=> a.PostedTime }._().transform{ [post: it.msg, comments: it.in('PostedOnComment').msg.toList()] }
==>{post=what is for dinner?, comments=[tacos]}
==>{post=hello, comments=[buenos dias, bongiorno]}
```